# Maven - transient dependency not being resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-starter

I created a `Spring Boot Starter Component` that depends on Kafka.

When I use the `Starter Component` as one of the dependencies in other project it fails to start due a missing class from Kafka library:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`

If I explicitly put Kafka as a dependency in the other project it works, but I would expect it not being necessary since Kafka is a dependency from the `Starter Component` and it should be resolved transiently

**EXCEPTION**

```
2022-12-03T14:05:42,321 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger: Running with Spring Boot v2.7.0, Spring v5.3.20
2022-12-03T14:05:42,323 INFO  [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication: The following 1 profile is active: "docker"
2022-12-03T14:05:43,161 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-03T14:05:43,228 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 56 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-03T14:05:43,500 ERROR [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication: Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.starter.autoconfigure.AppConfiguration.kafkaListenerContainerFactory
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.foo.bar.Application.main(Application.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:494)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:443)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.starter.autoconfigure.AppConfiguration.kafkaLi
stenerContainerFactory
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:513)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:436)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:532)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:520)
        ... 29 more
```

**STARTER COMPONENT**

```
package org.starter.autoconfigure;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer;
import org.starter.message.MyListener;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class AppConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory)
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> messageListenerContainer(
        ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf)
    {
        ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("my-topic");

        containerProps.setMessageListener(new MyListener());

        return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProps);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.starter</groupId>
    <artifactId>component-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>component-starter</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**OTHER PROJECT**

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>main-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>main-app</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>component-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please show your pom file of both project of the consuming project as well as of the magic-lib-1 project...

Comment: You could check the scope of the maven dependency in the starter component.

Comment: @Mena, it is default (compile)

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException nevermind then. As hinted by others, you probably want to produce an MVCE at this point.

Comment: I'll provide it soon

Comment: done. please let me know if you need something else

Comment: have you tried `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: compile time dependencies will be downloaded automatically, whereas `runtime` and `provided` aren't. So your reasoning doesn't make sense. Something makes it either `optional` or changes the scope to `provided`.

Comment: you right @M.Deinum. I removed my last update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a Nexus publishing issue. The starter component was being published with a generated pom.xml file without any dependency (without Kafka)

The issue was fixed when I published a new version pointing to a complete pom.xml file.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-customized-pom.html

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.0

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.starter</groupId>
<artifactId>component-starter</artifactId>
<version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>component-starter</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you explain why this pom.xml is relevant to the topic, please?